# How to checkall boxes angular.js using multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using this angular-bootstrap-multiselect ( https://github.com/sebastianha/angular-bootstrap-multiselect) library and I'm having trouble. I want to add an option called " select All"  in that drop down that would select all of the boxes. This is what I have so far for a dropdown which fetches the options from rest-api. I added " Select All" to the array( Badlist) so that it's the first option when you click the drop down. I just don't know how to make it so that EVERYTHING is selected once I click it.

```
<multiselect class="project-multiselect-dropdown"

            ng-model="Badlist.links"
            options="link.name for link in BadLinksList"
            data-multiple="true"
            scroll-after-rows="3"
            max-width="100"
            tabindex="1"
            ms-selected="{{Badlist.links}}"
            ng-change="incompleteEntries('BAD');

          </multiselect>
```

Right now it's just acting as a normal multi select drop down. I think that library has a checkAll() function but not sure where or how to use it.  I was thinking of adding a watcher in my controller, so that it activates the checkAll() function once it detects the user has clicked "Select all".I don't know how to call the checkAll() function in my $scope. watch. Usually i would do it in my view ( ng-click="checkAll())", but this is part of the drop down and not a button.

BTW here's the checkAll() function in that library ( just to save you guys time).

```
  scope.checkAll = function() {
                    if(!isMultiple) {
                        return;
                    }
                    angular.forEach(scope.items, function(item) {
                        item.checked = true;
                    });
                    setModelValue(true);
                };
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered [this](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) plugin instead? It comes with a 'select all' feature built in

Comment: yes I saw that but I think the project I'm working on is based entirely on that one because since it uses <multi-select>, i searched that in all the project files and saw that one in the bower components. SO I don't think I'm allowed to use anything else

Comment: That lib is a fork of [this](https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect) code, of which has an example where they have a 'check all' button - [see here](http://amitava82.github.io/angular-multiselect/). Perhaps you can see how they managed it

Comment: Any idea? I need to do something like this :  

$scope.watch("newBlock.links",function()){  

// if the Select all button is clicked, then call the function checkAll(),   which should check everything in the dropdown.  
}

Comment: @Ankh The checkAll() button they have is a separate button. It's easy because then i could just add ng-click= "checkAll()". but in my case, the Select All is PART of the drop down, so I don't know how to call checkAll(). You get me?